# When I ./logstash -f test.conf, it shows the error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

> [2017-01-05T15:18:50,554][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Pipeline
>   aborted due to error {:exception=>#,
>   :backtrace=>["file:/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/jruby/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/module.rb:45:in `const_missing'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:587:in
>   `ssl_socket_factory_from_options'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:394:in
>   `pool_builder'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:402:in
>   `pool'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:208:in
>   `initialize'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.2.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:19:in
>   `initialize'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.2.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:125:in
>   `build_pool'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.2.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:20:in
>   `initialize'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.2.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client_builder.rb:53:in
>   `build'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.2.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:188:in `build_client'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-5.2.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:13:in
>   `register'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:8:in
>   `register'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:37:in
>   `register'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:196:in
>   `start_workers'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:196:in
>   `start_workers'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:153:in
>   `run'",
>   "/opt/elk/logstash-5.0.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:250:in
>   `start_pipeline'"]}

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest version of Logstash 5.1.1 and try again? I know there were missing dependencies in initial 5.x versions

Comment: I  think  some problem  with java   "SSLConnectionSocketFactory not found in packages org.apache.http.client.methods"

Comment: Similar to [this one](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/resolved-logstash-fails-when-output-set-to-elasticsearch-sslconnectionsocketfactory-not-found-in-packages/41407)? It says RESOLVED but I don't see any useful answer.

Comment: can you paste your logstash config

Answer (score 1):

Try emptying the CLASSPATH by `export CLASSPATH=""` and then run the logstash command bacause I think it has predefined path in the application which it is trying to set and if that path is already present then it gives conflict of that.